# Is there an algorithm or a concept that enforces data structure to satisfy mathematical relation or formula?

Tags: algorithm, terminology

I'm looking for a **concept** which forces the system to satisfy simple mathematical (or physical) relations (or constraints). In other words, a system that always ensures consistency (consistency between internal variables) defined by the user. I have been searching for this for a few days, but I couldn't find anything similar to this. Maybe the terminology I used for a keyword is not relevant, so I would like to know the keywords if this is an existing concept/algorithm.

For clarification, suppose we have (e.g. in Python)

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.voltage=6
        self.current=3
        self.resistance=2

class System(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data

    def register_relation(self,relation):
        """
        Register a relation to System.
        System finds a way to calculate each variables.
        """
        pass

    def update(self,updated_variables):
        """
        Update variable values contained in updated_variables.
        Also update dependent variables based on the relations.
        """
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    s=System(Data())
    s.register_relation('voltage=current*resistance')

    s.update({'current':4,'resistance':2})
    print(s.data.voltage) # 8

    s.update({'voltage':9,'current':3})
    print(s.data.resistance) # 3
```

In the implementation, the relation `'voltage=current*resistance'` was registered in the `System` by `register_relation` method. Then, the `System` would know how to calculate each of `voltage`, `current` and `resistance`. After that, although only two of them were updated at the same time by `update` method, the rest was automatically calculated by the `System` and the consistency between variables was kept.

In further, there will be a lot of relations (constraints) in the system and it would require very complicated procedure in `update` method. Again, is there any concept/algorithm like this? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Logic programming, maybe. But it would help to know what happens in this example if you were to try to update only one variable.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you. I'll be searching for the logic programming. When updating only one variable, I think many ways can be possible to choose one solution among infinite set of solutions. I thought this is out of scope of this question, and I decided not to include this in the example. One way I would choose is that giving an additional information about the order of invariability (maybe a list of variables) when calling `register_relation`. Then, in the example, when only one variable was updated, the `system` will fix the invariable one from the rest, and finally update the last one.